# Rotate map to heading position (no compass)

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, rotation, mapkit

I'm new to iOS development, currently I'm writing an app, which is going to show some POI, while driving.

I want to rotate the map to match the position that vehicle is heading to (not using compass, but previous position), so the road in front of you is ahead current location on the map.

Any ideas how to achieve this using MKMapKit? Is this already built-in feature?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: did you found how you get the heading of MKMapCamera ?

Answer (score 2):

You can programmatically rotate an `MKMapView` by setting up an `MKMapCamera` for the view and modifying its `heading` property, for example:

```
MKMapCamera *newCamera = [[MKMapCamera alloc] init];
newCamera.heading = 90.0;
[mapView setCamera:newCamera animated:YES];
```

As for setting the heading based on the object you're tracking, it's then just a bit of math to determine the angle of the line between the old and new locations.

Comment: Yeah, I doing it that way, but when calculating the direction and setting new camera the animation focuses out (to entire globe) and in again every turn...

Comment: That may be because every time you're overwriting the map's camera with a new one. Try setting the `altitude` property of the camera along with the heading.